# Creating Pivot table in EXCEL VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I am trying to create a pivot in Excel with VBA.
This is my code:

```
Dim pc As PivotCache
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim lastrow As Integer

Set pc = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
    SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
    SourceData:=Worksheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address)

    Worksheets.Add
    Range("A1").Select

Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(ActiveCell, "EmptyLocationsPivot")

Set pf = pt.PivotFields("loc")
    pf.Orientation = xlRowField
    
lastrow = Worksheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A" & lastrow - 1).Copy
Worksheets.Add
Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    

Worksheets(1).Select

lastrow = Worksheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


If lastrow > 48 Then
    Range("A49:A" & lastrow).Cut
    Range("C1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End If

lastrow = Worksheets(1).Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

If lastrow > 48 Then
    Range("C49:A" & lastrow).Cut
    Range("D1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End If

MsgBox "Report Is Ready for Print!"

End Sub
```

I get the following error message:
Run-time error '5':
Invalid procedure call or argument

From what I read online the problem is with the way I reference the table destination.
I have tried with Worksheets(1).Range("A1") also, but with no success.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What line does arise the error?

Comment: ```Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(ActiveCell, "EmptyLocationsPivot")```

Comment: Did you try with `Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(Range("A3"), "EmptyLocationsPivot")`? As far as I know, a pivot Table cannot start at row 1 or 2. When you create it manually, all pivot tables by default start at row 3.

Comment: Amend the line that creates the cache: `Set pc = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
    SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
    SourceData:="'" & Worksheets(1).Name & "'!" & Worksheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address(referencestyle:=xlr1c1))`

Comment: I would try to edit tihs line of code to `Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=ActiveCell, TableName:="EmptyLocationsPivot")`

Comment: I tried all 3 suggestions and none of them worked. Thank you though for looking into the problem. I am getting the same error on the same row 
```Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(ActiveCell, "EmptyLocationsPivot")```

Comment: I've run your code and it might be that you didn't specify SourceData - no data no pvt table.  `SourceData:=Worksheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address)` Check if this region has any type of data, if not then this error occures. If you run it once you create new Sheet and it becomes Worksheets(1) - first in workbook and it's range("A1") is empty.